# Find the limit if it exists of a quotient with sine

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,1)}\frac{\sin(x^4-y^4)}{x^2-y^2}$

We can factor the argument of sine using the difference of squares, and likewise with the denominator but the problem is sine. Introducing polar coordinates doesn't help. I'm guessing I somehow have to use inequalities or perhaps the squeeze theorem to bound the limit but I am not sure what I would compare it to.

Comment: One method (though likely considered too “powerful”) is to expand the sine function as a Taylor series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}(x^4-y^4)=0$, then...

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}\frac{\sin(x^4-y^4)}{x^2-y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}\frac{\sin(x^4-y^4)}{x^4-y^4}\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}(x^2+y^2)=2\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t}t=2$$